# Blitting coastlines in matplotlib funcanimation with cartopy projection

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

In the following example, the mesh is drawn on top of my coastlines. I'd like the coastlines to be on top (and still use blitting). The only way I managed to get what I want is to draw the coastlines inside the init func and then draw them again in the update func. So I'm redrawing them for every frame. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-2,12,-2,12])
ax.coastlines('50m')

mesh = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(10,10))

def init():
    mesh.set_array([])
    return mesh,

def update(t):
    mesh.set_array(np.random.randn(9,9).ravel())
    return mesh,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, 100, init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to toggle the visibility of the coastlines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-2,12,-2,12])
cl = ax.coastlines('50m')

mesh = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(10,10))

def init():
    mesh.set_array([])
    cl.set_visible(False)
    return mesh, cl

def update(t):
    mesh.set_array(np.random.randn(9,9).ravel())
    cl.set_visible(True)
    return mesh, cl

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, 100, init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```